# How to test creation of files in home folder using Aruba

Tags: ruby, cucumber, aruba

I wish to test a Ruby command line application with Aruba and Cucumber. The application has a switch to create a dot file (such as .my_app) in the current user's home folder.  I prefer not to have the application create the file in the user's home folder when running the Aruba tests.

I'm looking for a method to create a temporary working directory inside the step definitions that will create the temporary folder and modify a path flag when the command line application is run.  Or is there some functionality built in Aruba that already provides something like this?

A sample test:

```
Feature: Initialize for user
  Scenario: Create a dot file in the user's home directory
    When I run `touch ~/.my_test_file`
    Then a file named "~/.my_test_file" should exist
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `env.rb`:

```
Before do
  set_env 'HOME', File.expand_path(File.join(current_dir, 'home'))
  FileUtils.mkdir_p ENV['HOME']
end
```

If you use this with Aruba, aruba will use `<project_root>/tmp/aruba/home`. Aruba then provides you with some nice cucumber steps to verify files are created, exist, etc.

Edit: I did a full write-up on my blog: http://ariejan.net/2014/04/15/testing-home-with-cucumber-and-aruba/

Comment: Nice solution.  Any thoughts on how to make this a cross-platform solution so that Windows users can also run the tests?

Answer (score 1):

Would [`fakefs`](https://github.com/defunkt/fakefs) help?  Instead of worrying about modifying your real filesystem, mock it out.

Comment: FakeFS is not used by the script when the script is executed from within backticks by Cucumber/Aruba.